# Storing the data into multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

For reading some data that describes the coordinates of lines I wrote the following code:

```
int numLines;
scanf("%d", &numLines);
int xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd;
for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &xStart, &yStart, &xEnd, &yEnd);
}
```

But I think it would be more useful for the rest of the program if I stored the data into multidimensional array. How do I do that and which is better: storing the data into one 4-dimensional or two 2-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Depends on how are you going to use your data later, on what is the possible coordinate range etc. Question is unclear.

Comment: Mutli-dimensional arrays are harder to work with.  But it just comes down to personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `scanf()` is wrong, you need to tell `scanf()` what to scan for, that is doen by means of the specifiers.

Without specifiers, it will interpret the passed parameter as the format string, which will cause problems, so you need

```
if (scanf("%s", &numLines) == 1)
 {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numLines ; ++i)
     {
        if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &xStart, &yStart, &xEnd, &yEnd) == 4)
         {
            /* process the data here */
         }
     }
 }
```

You don't really need an array of so many dimentions, you can use a `struct` for that, something like

```
struct Data 
 {
    int xStart;
    int xEnd;
    int yStart;
    int yEnd;
 };
```

now, you can create an array of `struct`s and many other things, and when using it you just need

```
struct Data data[SIZE];
int         j;

j = 0;
if (scanf("%s", &numLines) == 1)
 {
    for (int i = 0 ; ((i < numLines) && (j < SIZE)) ; ++i)
     {
        if (scanf("%d %d %d %d",
            &data[j].xStart, 
            &data[j].yStart, 
            &data[j].xEnd, 
            &data[j].yEnd) == 4)
         {
            j++;
         }
     }
 }
```

I would even go further, and define

```
struct Item
 {
    int start;
    int end;
 };

struct Items
 {
    struct Item x;
    struct Item y;
 };
```

which would make the code more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use structure.
For example
    struct Line{
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int endX;
    int endY;
    };

And then use array of this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than multidemensional array, I recommend to use 2 `struct`s. This is more natural.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define numlines 10

struct point {
   int x;
   int y;
};  
struct line {
   struct point a; /* start */
   struct point b; /* end */
};  

struct line lines[numlines];

int main() {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < numlines; i++ ) { 
        scanf("%d %d", &lines[i].a.x, &lines[i].a.y);
        scanf("%d %d", &lines[i].b.x, &lines[i].b.y);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You put a comment `/* start */` and `/* end */`, but you couldn't give that name to the fields? You say natural, well that would be natural, what is natural about `a` and `b`?